# If Derivative at each point $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is an orthogonal matrix then $f(x) = Ox +b $

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-calculus

Let $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ map such that *it's Derivative at each point $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is an orthogonal matrix* i.e. $Df_x \in O(n,\Bbb R) \text{  , } \forall x \in \Bbb R^n$ . Then prove that $$f(x) = Ox +b \text{ , for some fixed } O \in O(n,\Bbb R) \text{ ,} \forall x \in \Bbb R^n$$

I have no idea about this problem, so couldn't make any attempt.

Comment: While the question clearly is a duplicate of the linked one, I would still like to see a direct elementary answer if there is one (Alexandre's refers to theory, and David's makes the extra assumption that $f\in C^2$). It could of course be posted as an answer to the earlier question.

Comment: If $\gamma(t)$ is a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the image of $\gamma(t)$ under $f$ has the same length as $\gamma(t)$. This shows every line segment is mapped to a line segment of equal length.

Comment: @Marco: don't get the conclusion. Every line segment is mapped to a *curve* of equal length, but why a line segment? The endpoints are not fixed.

Comment: This only shows the map is distance non-increasing. Since the volumes are preserved, would this be sufficient to finish the problem?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, this is a corollary of Liouville's Theorem on rigidity of conformal maps (in dimension $\geq 3$). Liouville proved his theorem with fairly high regularity requirements, but a proof under only the $C^1$ hypothesis was given by Hartman in 1958:

*Hartman, Philip*, [**On isometries and on a theorem of Liouville**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01187401), Math. Z. 69, 202-210 (1958). [ZBL0097.38203](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0097.38203).

Since then, the theorem has been proved under progressively lower regularity assumption ($1$-quasiregular). None of the arguments are easy.